# Differences between the many words for dinner

Tags: words, word-choice, food

According to my dictionary, the following words all mean the same thing: "Dinner":
[夜]{よる}ご[飯]{はん}, [晩]{ばん}ご[飯]{はん}, [晩飯]{ばんめし}, [晩食]{ばんしょく}, [夕]{ゆう}ご[飯]{はん}, [夕飯]{ゆうはん(ゆうめし)}, [夕食]{ゆうしょく}

A similar thing goes for "Breakfast" ([朝]{あさ}ご[飯]{はん}, [朝飯]{あさめし}, [朝食]{ちょうしょく}) and "Lunch" ([昼]{ひる}ご[飯]{はん}, [昼飯]{ひるめし}, [昼食]{ちゅうしょく})

What's the difference between them? Are they mostly interchangeable? Which ones are more commonly used or is it a matter of preference? etc.
My current understanding is that the ones that end in ご飯 are politer.

Comment: 「晩食」って、初めて聞きました・・・ww

Comment: +「[夜飯]{よるめし}」? ([夜食]{やしょく} is something different)

Comment: Let's not forget [晩餐]{ばんさん}.

Comment: @JesseGood 晩餐 sounds to me like a feast/ごちそう... http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/181215/m0u/　Is [夕餉]{ゆうげ} archaic? http://www.e-rogers.jp/shop/home/502/item_img/211367_detailImage1.jpg

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[夕・晩・夜] + [ご飯・飯・食]

(1) ~~ + ご[飯]{はん}
We have [夕]{ゆう}ご[飯]{はん}, [晩]{ばん}ご[飯]{はん}, [夜]{よる}ご[飯]{はん}. 
I don't see much difference among them. We (especially children and women) use ~~ご飯 most in daily conversation. I normally use 晩ご飯 and 夜ご飯, and I think my mother uses 夕ご飯 too.

(2) ~~ + [食]{しょく}
We have [夕食]{ゆうしょく}. I didn't know [晩食]{ばんしょく} so I googled it, and I got some 30,000 results. It's less common so you wouldn't need to know 晩食 to pass JLPT. ([夜食]{やしょく} is "bedtime snack".) 
~~食 sounds politer and more formal than ~~ご[飯]{はん} and ~~[飯]{はん/めし}. When you go to a hotel or an inn([旅館]{りょかん}), you will hear/see:

> 「(ご)[夕食]{ゆうしょく}は、６[時]{じ}からとなっております。」
>   「[夕食]{ゆうしょく}[付]{つ}き:[一泊一万円]{いっぱくいちまんえん}。」

but not

> 「[晩]{ばん}(or[夕]{ゆう}/[夜]{よる})ご[飯]{はん}は、６時からとなっております」
>   「[夕飯]{ゆうはん}/[晩飯]{ばんめし}は、６時からとなっております。」
>   「晩(or夜/夕)ご飯付き:一泊一万円。」
>   「夕飯付き/晩飯付き:一泊１万円。」

(3) ~~ + [飯]{はん/めし}
We have [夕飯]{ゆうはん} and [晩飯]{ばんめし}. (I think 夕飯 can also be read ゆうめし but I think only guys use that word, in casual speech. Here again, I think you can pass JLPT without knowing the reading ゆうめし.) 
As @istrasci-san mentions, "~~[飯]{めし}" sounds masculine and rough.
I googled 夜飯 and よるめし, and got quite a few results, though there're a lot of Chinese pages, too (Please see @Flaw's comment below). Anyway it's not so common so I think you can survive in Japan without knowing 夜飯/よるめし.  
My mother sometimes uses お[夕飯]{ゆうはん} when talking to us or to our neighbors, like

> 「そろそろ、お[夕飯]{ゆうはん}の[支度]{したく}しなくっちゃ。」
>   「そろそろ、[晩ご飯]{ばんごはん}/[夜ご飯]{よるごはん}の支度しなくっちゃ。」

but she wouldn't say:

> 「そろそろ、[夕食]{ゆうしょく}の支度しなくっちゃ。」, or 
>  
>   「そろそろ、[晩飯]{ばんめし}の支度しなくっちゃ。」unless she's trying to sound funny.

Comment: In Chinese we have 隔夜飯 which means leftovers from yesterday's food.

Comment: So in general order of politeness, it goes: ~[食]{しょく}, ~ご[飯]{はん}, ~[飯]{はん} and then ~[飯]{めし}, with ~[飯]{はん} being the "neutral" politeness?

Comment: @小太郎　I think (お)[夕飯]{ゆうはん} can be a bit politer than ~ご[飯]{はん}. So I think it'd be like... ~[食]{しょく}＞~[飯]{はん}＞(or≧?)~ご[飯]{はん}＞~[飯]{めし}

Comment: @小太郎, formality and politeness are not the same. ~食 is formal (not very, but a bit), i.e. you'd see it in newspapers etc. ~ご飯 is polite (although almost neutral) but not formal, and would therefore be more common in speech. These dimensions have some correlation, but are slightly different in nature.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience...

The ones ending in `ご飯` are most polite.  Actually, using them around friends may get you some strange looks.  The ones ending in `飯（めし）` seem very informal, somewhat "rough", and mainly used by men.  The ones ending in `食` seem to be the most neutral and most widely-used.

However, they may regionally have different acceptance levels and/or usage frequencies.  I lived in Osaka, and there (as I mentioned), saying `晩飯` or `夕飯` is a little bit "rough" and only used by men.  This may be different in other regions though.

Comment: The ones ending in ～食【しょく】 are the most widely-used? They seem more formal to me, for some reason. I definitely agree about ～飯【めし】, though; they have a distinct masculine feel.

Comment: What about 夜 vs 晩 vs 夕?

Comment: I have to say that out here in the inaka I hear every kind of word for all of them used by just about everyone, so ultimately I think your choice of meal word won't *really* matter that much